# sed/awk unix csv file modification

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a directory that is receiving .csv files.

```
column1,column2,column3,columb4
value1,0021,value3,value4,
value1,00211,value3,value4,
```

I want remove the header, pad the second column to 6 digits and add `":"` so it is in `HH:MM:SS` format. e.g.

```
value1,00:00:21,value3,value4,
value1,00:02:11,value3,value4,
```

I can pad the characters to 6 digits using awk but I am not sure to insert the semicolumn every 2 characters for the second $2. Else can this be fully done in sed? which would be better for performance?

Thank you

Comment: With GNU awk, see https://ideone.com/gP0RgX

Comment: why the `00211` is `000211` instead of `002101`?

Answer (score 2):

You may do it all with GNU `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$2=sprintf("%06d", $2); $2=substr($2,1,2) gensub(/.{2}/,":&","g",substr($2,3))}1' file
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/7ACI6K)

**Details**

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` - sets input/output field separator to a comma
- `$2=sprintf("%06d", $2)` - pads Field 2 with zeros
- `$2=substr($2,1,2)""gensub(/.{2}/,":&","g",substr($2,3))` - sets Field 2 value equal to a first two chars of the field (`substr($2,1,2)`) plus the field substring starting from the third char with `:` inserted before each two char chunk.
- `1` - default print action.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` formatting + substitution *magic*:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS = OFS = "," }
     NR > 1{ $2=sprintf("%06d", $2); gsub(/[0-9]{2}/, "&:", $2); 
             $2=substr($2, 0, 8); print }' file
```

The output:

```
value1,00:00:21,value3,value4,
value1,00:02:11,value3,value4,
```

Comment: Thank you. If i want to expand this to e.g.

if $3 != "Processed" then remove line. How would the syntax be?

Answer (score 1):

with `sed`

```
$ sed -nE '2,$s/,([0-9]+)/,00000\1/;s/,0+(..)(..)(..),/,\1:\2:\3,/p' file

value1,00:00:21,value3,value4,
value1,00:02:11,value3,value4,
```

I think it can be simplified little bit.